# Is it possible to go from an Array[Row] to a DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

If I call `collect` on a `DataFrame`, I will get an `Array[Row]`. But I'm wondering if it possible to go back to a DataFrame from that result or an `Array[Row]` in general.

For example:

```
rows = df.select("*").collect()
```

Is there some way to do something like this:

```
import df.sparkSession.implicits._
newDF = rows.toDF()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to provide a `List[Row]`, as long as you provide as schema. Then you can use `SparkSession.createDataFrame`

```
def createDataFrame(rows: List[Row], schema: StructType): DataFrame
```

There is no variant of `toDF` that can be used here.

In general you should avoid `collecting` and converting result back to `DataFrame`.